# Force null values to be considered as earlier dates using the row_number function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table that lists documents associated with a patient.  Some documents will have a `RECEIVED_TIME`, while other will not.  I need to have the most-recent `RECEIVED_TIME` if it exists.

I'm using the `row_number` function to create a sequence number (`SEQ`) based on the `RECEIVED_TIME`; I would restrict the records to `SEQ=1`.

Unfortunately, `null` values are being considered as 'later' than the `RECEIVED_TIME`, when I need them to be considered as 'earlier'.

The SQL:

```
with

data as
(
  select  v.*
          -- sort the most-recent value first
          ,row_number() over (partition by pat_id order by RECEIVED_TIME desc) SEQ
  from (

         select 'A' PAT_ID, 100 ID, 'Obtain' STATUS, '2019-04-19 00:00:00' RECEIVED_TIME from dual
         union all
         select 'A' PAT_ID, 101 ID, 'Unable to Obtained' STATUS, null RECEIVED_TIME from dual

          union all
         select 'B' PAT_ID, 102 ID, 'Obtained' STATUS, '2019-04-18 00:00:00' RECEIVED_TIME from dual
          union all
         select 'B' PAT_ID, 103 ID, 'Obtained' STATUS, '2019-04-19 00:00:00' RECEIVED_TIME from dual

         union all

         select 'C' PAT_ID, 104 ID, 'Unable to Obtained' STATUS, null RECEIVED_TIME from dual

       ) v
)

select  *
from  data
```

Results:

```
PAT_ID,ID,STATUS,RECEIVED_TIME,SEQ
A,101,Unable to Obtained,<NULL>,1  <-- null is 'later'
A,100,Obtain,2019-04-19 00:00:00,2
B,103,Obtained,2019-04-19 00:00:00,1
B,102,Obtained,2019-04-18 00:00:00,2
C,104,Unable to Obtained,<NULL>,1
```

Desired results:

```
PAT_ID,ID,STATUS,RECEIVED_TIME,SEQ
A,100,Obtain,2019-04-19 00:00:00,1
A,101,Unable to Obtained,<NULL>,2  <-- null should be 'earlier'
B,103,Obtained,2019-04-19 00:00:00,1
B,102,Obtained,2019-04-18 00:00:00,2
C,104,Unable to Obtained,<NULL>,1
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple: add NULLS LAST to the ORDER BY clause in the window function:

```
with data as
(
  select  v.*
          -- sort the most-recent value first
          ,row_number() over (partition by pat_id 
                               order by RECEIVED_TIME desc nulls last) SEQ
  from (    
     select 'A' PAT_ID, 100 ID, 'Obtain' STATUS, '2019-04-19 00:00:00' RECEIVED_TIME from dual union all
     select 'A' PAT_ID, 101 ID, 'Unable to Obtained' STATUS, null RECEIVED_TIME from dual union all
     select 'B' PAT_ID, 102 ID, 'Obtained' STATUS, '2019-04-18 00:00:00' RECEIVED_TIME from dual union all
     select 'B' PAT_ID, 103 ID, 'Obtained' STATUS, '2019-04-19 00:00:00' RECEIVED_TIME from dual union all    
     select 'C' PAT_ID, 104 ID, 'Unable to Obtained' STATUS, null RECEIVED_TIME from dual
           ) v
)    
select  *
from  data
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e8b87ea9ad2cd1ef1be32c9896136a4)

Comment: Simple.  Thank you!